# Android :How to load image dynamically from server by its name from SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview, android-sqlite

I am new to android and I'm facing an issue while displaying image from server based its name from Sqlite

ie:
I  stored only image name (text) in SQLite database (column name images) and I want to load images from Server based on the sqlite image name the image want to display in imageview

In server I create a folder like Cars in that folder I store images with car names..but in sqlite I just add a carname in text format with .jpeg

I have two column names in my DB:

- first is Car name
- Second is Car Detail

When user selects the Car name, in next activity the user can see the Car details with images.
Here I display Details, But I don't know How to display Car Images From Server

Thanks

Here is my Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_activity);

    detailtext= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail);
    imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images);

    Intent intent= getIntent();
    final String selectedData = intent.getStringExtra("selectedItem");
    actionBar.setTitle(selectedData);

    dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
    try {
        dbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor=dbHelper.getdetails(sqLiteDatabase, selectedData);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

    detailtext.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        String imagename = cursor.getString(1);
        String imageUrl = "http://your_server/car/" + imagename ;

        Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView );
    }
```

Note:Image Field is the 4th Column https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqvOQ.png
and in server i put image in www.server.com/cars/carnames.jpg

in sqlite i just paste the image name with .jpg ex:carnames.jpg

SqliteDbHelper

```
public Cursor getdetails(SQLiteDatabase db,String img)
    {
        db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor=db.query("record",new String[]{DETAIL,IMAGES,ITEMNO + " as _id"},SUBCATEGORY + "='" +img+"'",null,null,null,null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: `I am storing only image name` ... hopefully, you are adding the full path when retrieving the image names

Comment: If you are using sqlite why did you tag sql server?

Comment: If you are able to get the full URL of the image whats the problem then?

Comment: @Nanoc in server i create a folder like Cars in that folder i store a images with car names..but in sqlite i just add a carname in text format...

Comment: So are you able to reconstruct each image url? should be as easy as having that folder url and add each image name right?

Comment: yes...i have two colum names in my DB first is Car name and Second is Car Detail When user Select the Car name in next activity the user can see the Car details With Images Here i Display Details But I dont know How to Display Car Images From Server Thanks @Nanoc

Comment: what the problem exactly now, after trying the 2 answers

Comment: My Problem is When i am trying to Implement the Second Answer The Image was Display But The SAme Image was Display to all The Fields (ie) if select Audi Car I want to Display Audi car Images But here When i select Audi car it Display BMW car Images @MounirElfassi

Comment: My Database FLow is Like this Only Car,Bus,Lorry(Title) ** if i select car It Display **BMW,AUDI,JAGUAR (Subcateory) if i select BMW it display Bmw car details(Details) With Bmw Car Image(Images) @MounirElfassi

Answer (score 4):

If you want to load images from SQlite then I suggest you save the file/file location if the data is stored locally, for the showing of a single image on all image view it is because you are only loading a single image, you might want to put all your ids in an array and passing it to the db, the db query should also return an array/arraylist of image locations which you should load into your image views using a `for loop` e.g I have a query that loads a bunch of images from my SQLite database, this displays sub-category images of a certain category  named shoes so we have images of `smart shoes`, `Casual shoes` and more I pass an an Id as parameter

```
  public ArrayList<CategoryItem> getAllSubCategories(int mtargetID) throws SQLException{



    ArrayList<CategoryItem> myshoes = new ArrayList<>();
    // Select All Query



    String sQuery = " SELECT "+Constant.CATEGORY_TB_ID+",  "+Constant.SUB_DESCRIPTION+
            ", "+Constant.SUB_IMAGEPATH+" FROM  "+Constant.CATEGORY_TABLE+
    " INNER JOIN "+Constant.SUB_CATEGORY_TABLE+" ON "+Constant.CATEGORY_TB_ID +" = " +Constant.SUB_CATEGORY_FK
   + " WHERE "+Constant.CATEGORY_TB_ID +" = ?";

    String[] args = new String[1];
    args[0] = String.valueOf(mtargetID);


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sQuery, args);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            CategoryItem myShoesItem = new CategoryItem();

            //my shoe image path on external storage
            myShoeItem.setmCategoryImgPath(cursor.getString(2));
            //i add my image paths to my array list
            myshoes.add(myShoeItem);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return my arraylist for display into my imageview
    return mshoes;

}
```

on the receiving side I then transverse through my araylist

```
   for(int i = 0; i <getAllSubCategories.size(); i++ )
  {

       imageView.setImageUri(getAllSubCategories.get(i).getmCategoryImgPath())
   }
```

with this method you will set images to all your imageviews.

Answer (score 1):

You have the path "url" request to the server? like this:

> http://server_ip/api/images?imageName="The name you image here"

Then do you need use some lib to load image from server, see this:

[Android Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

So, something like this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://server_ip/api/images?imageName="The name you image here.png/jpeg").into(imageView);
```

Comment: i have two colum names in my DB first is Car name and Second is Car Detail When user Select the Car name in next activity the user can see the Car details With Images Here i Display Details But I dont know How to Display Car Images From Server Thanks @Anderson C Silva

Comment: in server i create a folder like Cars in that folder i store a images with car names..but in sqlite i just add a carname in text format... @Anderson C Silva

Comment: @SabarishKarthick there what?

Comment: check my above comments plz @Anderson C Silva Image was Not Displayed

Comment: Ok, do you can contact me by skype: anderson_anndre

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that in your server, you've created a directory called `cars/` and all images are in jpeg format and also with same file name as their real names. If I'm correct, so your can use codes below.

```java
Intent intent= getIntent();
final String selectedData = intent.getStringExtra("selectedItem");
actionBar.setTitle(selectedData);

// This a image declared in XML for displaying car image
ImageView carImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.carImage);    

// URL of this car's image
String imageUrl = "http://your_server_address/cars/" + carName + ".jpeg";

// Use Picasso library to load that image
Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(carImageView);
```

**Note:** [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is a fearure rich library for fetching images from network in Android.

Comment: Thanks It Load Images From Server But It Display a Single Images For all the Fields..example if we want to fetch Text Details we use cursor.getString(0); what abt Images? @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: @SabarishKarthick Are image file names exactly equal to name of cars?

Comment: yes ex:in server cars folder i place a Car Image name as "Audi.jpeg" the same name was used in sqlite Column name @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: if i select Bmw car in listview the detail view display Bmw car details But it Display Audi Car Image Hope u Undestand What i am Trying To Say ! @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: @SabarishKarthick So, you should pass "Bmw" as `carName`. Did you?

Comment: Yes in my Databse I have Colun name like Car,Car_details,Images In car Field i add Car names,In Car Details I add Details abt Cars,in Image Field I add images ex:BMW.jpeg..the Same name(BMW.jpeg) was Used in server to Save Images @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: @SabarishKarthick So, if the image column is 3rd column, then you should use `cursor.getString(2)` to get image file name.

Comment: i know that but i dont know where to Add in Picasso @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: @SabarishKarthick Just add this line: `String carName = cursor.getString(2)`.

Comment: `String imageUrl = "http://your_server_address/carImages/" + SqlLiteDbHelper.IMAGES ;` If i Use this it display Images But it display All the same Images For All the Fields...If i use  this  `String imagename = cursor.getString(2);
            String imageUrl = "http://your_server_address/carImages/" + imagename ;

            Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView );` it does Not Display Images @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: @SabarishKarthick What's `SqlLiteDbHelper.IMAGES` ? What string is behind this? Also make sure all file names are followed by `.jpg` extension.

Comment: Check My Updated Code and Notes  Pls @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: @SabarishKarthick Please post your SQL query.

Comment: YA Done @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: @SabarishKarthick What's `String img` in that method?

Comment: it want to display Images based on the selection of Subcategory ie:if i select Audi in subcategory the detail Activity want to display Both Detail column name With Images @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: @SabarishKarthick You said: SqlLiteDbHelper.IMAGES did work. So what's it? what string?

Comment: My Database FLow is Like this Only **Car,Bus,Lorry(Title) ** if i select car It Display **BMW,AUDI,JAGUAR (Subcateory)** if i select BMW it display Bmw car details(Details) With Bmw Car Image(Images) @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: Subcategory wants to Display Based On Title Selection...Details and Images want to display based on Subcategory Selection  and  My Database FLow is Like this Only Car,Bus,Lorry(Title) ** if i select car It Display **BMW,AUDI,JAGUAR (Subcateory) if i select BMW it display Bmw car details(Details) With Bmw Car Image(Images) @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: @SabarishKarthick Try debugging your app to see what's going on.

Comment: it doesnot show any error it simply doesnot display Images from Server all the flow was working perfectly..it display details and images not displaying @Hi I'm frogatto

Comment: @SabarishKarthick Check your images' URL. Try running debugger in your app and check URL strings. They should be exact.